# Mongo Java query for and/or combination

Tags: java, mongodb

I need a Java driver mongo query for and/or combination - 
for ex -

suppose I have a  collection user have 3 field named a, b, c.

Now I have to perform find query like -

```
user.find({$and :[{"a":"text"},{$or :[{"b":"text"},{"c":"text"}]}]})
```

This mongo console query give correct result.
How I apply this with JAVA mongo driver.

Please help
Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think you need the `$and` here, because when you have conditions multiple fields in your query, they are `$and`-ed automatically. The only situation where you need `$and` is when you have multiple conditions (usually with different operators) on *the same* field.

Comment: Also, do you use the new QueryBuilder API or the old API where you use nested DBObject's and DBList's?

Comment: Thanks for reply Philipp, I am using old DBObject API. Can you please tell me the query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use following query

```
DBCollection userCollection = db.getCollection("collection");

BasicDBObject orQuery = new BasicDBObject();
List<BasicDBObject> obj1 = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();
obj1.add(new BasicDBObject("a", "text"));
obj1.add(new BasicDBObject("b", "text"));
orQuery.put("$or", obj1);

BasicDBObject andQuery = new BasicDBObject();
List<BasicDBObject> obj = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();
obj.add(new BasicDBObject("c", "text"));
obj.add(orQuery);
andQuery.put("$and", obj);

System.out.println(andQuery.toString());

DBCursor cursor = userCollection.find(andQuery);
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(cursor.next());
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nilesh, really helpful!