# find with objectId as foreign key in java

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I have a collection as sample below

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("60e8216624446e5662ebbcfb"),

    appUserId: 'abc',
    changeAmount: 1,
    changeMultiplier: 1,
    changeRoundOffUpTo: 100,
    createdAt: 2021-07-09T10:13:58.671Z,
    description: '',
    roundUpAmount: 1,
    status: 4,
    updatedAt: 2022-01-06T04:03:20.163Z,
    bucketId: ObjectId("60e80a4124446e5662e37abc"),
    timestamp: 2021-07-09T10:13:58.671Z
  }
```

So I get bucketId I have to find all the collections with that bucket Id
we have something **bucketId: mongoose_2.Types.ObjectId(bucketId)** in mongo is there anything in java which can find by bucketId
I tried with
findAllByBucketId(Its taking only id not object")

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797935/how-to-query-documents-using-id-field-in-java-mongodb-driver

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongo Java query for and/or combination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30236639/mongo-java-query-for-and-or-combination)